# Find all Products by Tag in Rails with ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, spree, has-many

This is probably something very simple but I'm looking for the optimal way of retrieving all Products by Tag, so to speak.  This is with Spree, so I should stick to the way they have modeled their data.  It's actually `Product` and `Taxon` (like category, brand, etc.)

So if Product `has_and_belongs_to_many :taxons` and Taxon `has_and_belongs_to_many :products`, what's the best way to find all products by a Taxon?

Something like:

```
@taxon = Taxon.find_by_permalink('categories/')
@products = Product.find_by_taxon(@taxon)
```

... but I'm not sure what goes into that last method (just made up the name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're going to just simply say if there's only one Taxon

```
@products = @taxon.products
```

If there's multiple we require a slightly different method. But even then you could just

```
@products = @taxons.inject([]) {|taxon| taxon.products}
```

Comment: super basic :p, lost in it all right now. thanks for the help!

Comment: This will cause an N+1 query problem

Answer (score 2):

```
@taxon = Taxon.find_by_permalink('categories', :include => :products)
```

This will eager-load the products so you can access them through

```
@taxon.products
```

without it hitting the database again. This is the more efficient form of just using .products that avoids N+1 query problems.

Answer (score 0):

Won't `Taxon.find_by_permalink('categories/').products` suffice?

EDIT: Oh and for multiple taxons you could try something like this:

```
Product.find(:all, :include => :products_taxons, :conditions => { :products_taxons => {:taxon_id => [1,2,3]} }) # will find products with taxons with id 1, 2 or 3
```

Comment: Well, that will find a Taxon but since he wants to find all products by Taxon we need a little more.

Comment: obviously you'd need to check that Taxon.find_by_permalink returned something, or alternatively use Taxon.find_by_permalink('categories/').try(:products)

Comment: Hmm, I don't see why that does not retrieve all products with a given taxon.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working in Spree 2.1.0.beta with the following customizations:

Based on the answer here: [Finding records with two specific records in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891331/finding-records-with-two-specific-records-in-another-table)

I added a new product scope in /app/models/spree/product_decorator.rb

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do
  add_search_scope :in_all_taxons do |*taxons|
    taxons = get_taxons(taxons)
    id = arel_table[:id]
    joins(:taxons).where(spree_taxons: { id: taxons }).group(id).having(id.count.eq(taxons.size))
  end
end
```

Then used the new scope by adding it to /app/models/spree/base_decorator.rb

```
Spree::Core::Search::Base.class_eval do
    def get_base_scope
      base_scope = Spree::Product.active
      base_scope = base_scope.in_all_taxons(taxon) unless taxon.blank?
      base_scope = get_products_conditions_for(base_scope, keywords)
      base_scope = add_search_scopes(base_scope)
      base_scope
    end
end
```

Now I can use the standard search helper to retrieve products (which means I can still supply keywords, etc along with the multiple taxons):

```
# taxon_ids is an array of taxon ids
@searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(:taxon => taxon_ids))
@products = @searcher.retrieve_products
```

This works for me and felt pretty painless.  However, I'm open to better options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a product by its tags you can use `tagged_with`

Example

```
Spree::Product.tagged_with("example")
```

Will return the products with the tag "example"

Source: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on