# Finding records with two specific records in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Product` model that `has_and_belongs_to_many :taxons`, and I want to find all products that are in specific taxons.

For example, if a product belongs to both the "Ruby on Rails" and "Shirts" taxon, I want that product to be returned in the dataset, but *not* if it only belongs to either "Ruby on Rails" or "Shirts"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this problem a while back, thankfully there is a nice solution.

```
def self.has_taxons(taxons)
  id = arel_table[:id]
  Product.joins(:taxons).where(taxons: { name: taxons }).group(id).having(id.count.eq(taxons.size))
end
```

Comment: @RyanBigg Also take a look at this gem: https://github.com/ernie/squeel. It adds a layer of abstraction over ARel. It allows you to build more concise/readable queries. Even while `taxons.name.in taxons` or `taxons.name >> taxons` isn't so much better than nested hashes, you'll appreciate this chaining if you ever need more than 2 levels of joining. And you can make your `having` stuff w/o calling `arel_table`, like: `having{count(id) == some_size}`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer from @samuel is exactly what I was looking for, but I wanted to be able to still supply keywords to the search while filtering by Taxon1 AND Taxon2 and TaxonN.  I don't ever need to do a Taxon1 OR Taxon2 search, so I made the following customizations.  There might be a less hacky way to do this, but it works great for me.

I added a new product scope in /app/models/spree/product_decorator.rb

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do
    add_search_scope :in_all_taxons do |*taxons|
        taxons = get_taxons(taxons)
        id = arel_table[:id]
        joins(:taxons).where(spree_taxons: { id: taxons }).group(id).having(id.count.eq(taxons.size))
    end
end
```

Then used the new scope by adding it to /app/models/spree/base_decorator.rb

```
Spree::Core::Search::Base.class_eval do
    def get_base_scope
        base_scope = Spree::Product.active
        base_scope = base_scope.in_all_taxons(taxon) unless taxon.blank?
        base_scope = get_products_conditions_for(base_scope, keywords)
        base_scope = add_search_scopes(base_scope)
        base_scope
    end
end
```

Now I can use the standard search helper to retrieve products (which means I can still supply keywords, etc along with the multiple taxons):

```
# taxon_ids is an array of taxon ids
@searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(:taxon => taxon_ids))
@products = @searcher.retrieve_products
```

This works for me and felt pretty painless. However, I'm open to better options.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming performance isn't a requirement:

```
a = Taxon.find_by_name!('Ruby on Rails').products.pluck(:id)
b = Taxon.find_by_name!('Shirts').products.where(:id => a)
```